# Get Element Count from within a Slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Consider the following Vue component:

```
<template>

    <!-- Carousel -->
    <div class="carousel-container">

        <div ref="carousel" class="carousel">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>

    </div>

</template>

<script>

    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                items: this.$refs.carousel.querySelector('*')
            }
        },

        computed: {
            count: function () {
                return this.items.length;
            }
        },

        created () {
            console.log(this.count);
        }

    }

</script>
```

The above does not work, and I think that is because I am attempting to reference `refs` in the data object.

I am trying to get the `count` of DOM elements within the `.carousel` element. How should I go about achieving this?

### Update

After doing some further research, I have found that it is possible to achieve like so:

```
<script>

    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                items: []
            }
        },

        computed: {
            count: function () {
                return this.items.length;
            }
        },

        mounted () {
            this.items = this.$refs.carousel.children;
            console.log(this.count);
        }

    }

</script>
```

**However**, I am not confident that this is the best way to achieve this. I appreciate that 'best' is subjective, but is anyone aware of a 'better' way to achieve this?

Comment: If you use components in the slots instead of plain HTML elements, you can also use `this.$children`

Answer (score 1):

I think a simpler, more straightforward way of counting the elements in  tag would be more like this:

```
<script>

    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                count: 0
            }
        },

        mounted () {
            this.count = this.$refs.carousel.children.length;
            console.log(this.count);
        }

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score -8):

We can get all the elements inside the .carousel class using below

```
var matched = $(".carousel *");
var total elements = matched.length;
```

if you need only slot count, you can use below

```
var matched = $(".carousel slot");
var total elements = matched.length;
```